# Using Voice Enabled for React or Angular using Amplify Interactions

Tags: angular, reactjs, aws-amplify, amazon-lex

```
I am using aws-amplify interaction : https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/
```

Interaction code is :

```
 <ChatBot
          title="My Bot"
          theme={myTheme}
          botName="OrderFlowers"
          welcomeMessage="Welcome, how can I help you today?"
          onComplete={this.handleComplete.bind(this)}
          clearOnComplete={true}
          conversationModeOn={false}
          voiceEnabled={true}
          voiceConfig={customVoiceConfig}
        />

 const customVoiceConfig = {
      silenceDetectionConfig: {
          time: 2000,
          amplitude: 0.2
      }   
  }
```

**I am following this link** : https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/interactions

```
    *While using voice enabled interaction I am getting this error. When I press the voice button.*

    [enter image description here][1]Aws_restJson1_1.ts:834 Uncaught (in promise) **BadRequestException: Invalid Request: The header x-amz-content-sha256 must be set to the literal string** UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD.
        at http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:91237:42
        at step (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:318206:17)
        at Object.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:318137:14)
        at fulfilled (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:318092:24)

      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4heUC.png
```

Can anyone help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with amplify chatbot ui component and I've opened an issue for that in aws-sdk repo: https://github.com/aws-samples/create-react-app-auth-amplify/issues/18
After doing some analysis, I believe the lib needs to be adjusted a little bit in order to address this error.